# How can I change the color of a UITextField clearButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface, uitextfield

I would like to change the color of the clearButton that appaers when you are writting on a UItextField. Any suggestion? I am not an advanced interface developer and I have no idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should create your own UIButton (with image, you'll need a png of you desiderated button), instance it and put this button in the rightView of your UITextField.

```
CGFloat myWidth = 26.0f;
CGFloat myHeight = 30.0f;
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, myWidth, myHeight)];
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myButtonImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myButtonImage"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doClear:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

myTextField.rightView = myButton;
myTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing;
```

You could need to refine alignments using (these are example values):

```
myButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, 0, 0);
```

Then, you will need to implement method -(void) doClear(id)sender; that will clear your textfield.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would try it!

Comment: if you need the button to be shown "while editing" you need to change the `rightViewMode` to `UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing`

Comment: I made a sample clear button that you can use. https://www.chillysky.com/apps/Clear.png

Comment: @JackHumphries Do you have a working link to this image?

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 4

I used Giorgio's answer and this is what I went with :

```
let height = textField.bounds.height / 3
let width = height + 10
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

let myButton = UIButton(frame: rect)

myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "clear button white"), for: .normal)

textField.rightView = myButton
textField.rightViewMode = .always

myButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
```

The normal one :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygS2P.png)

This one :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6D9a.png)